# How to split string into rows based on condition in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

i have a comma separated string as below

M1: TestString1, M2: TestString2, M3: TestString3, M4: TestString4, M5: TestString5, M6: TestString6, M7: TestString7

i need output as

| code | String |
| --- | --- |
| M1 | TestString1 |
| M2 | TestString2 |
| M3 | TestString3 |
| M4 | TestString4 |
| M5 | TestString5 |
| M6 | TestString6 |
| M7 | TestString7 |

can any1 help me in getting the query

Comment: @OldProgrammer - certainly not that thread; here the OP has multiple columns, not just multiple values to be split into a single column.

Comment: Your input string looks very much like an array of key-value pairs. JSON is a perfect "language" to express such data in string format. Is it possible to change the **input** so that it is a proper JSON string? (Meaning, wherever this string is coming from - can that process, which generates your input string, generate a JSON instead?) In any case, on the database end - as a poor substitute for what I suggested above - you can first process the input string to make it a valid JSON; then split it with JSON tools. This requires version 12.1; what is your Oracle version?